# Join VM to Windows Domain using VPN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

*This seems basic and common but I cannot find anything helping me with this, surprisingly.*

**Question:** anything special to do in a VM to enable VPN connection in the guest?

**Context:** I have a Windows10 VM that I need to connect to a corporate Windows Domain of my client's company; this is done using VPN in this company. Host is my own Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, running the VM in VirtualBox. VPN connection must go from VM to server; VPN connection must not be from host to server then shared from host to VM.

The VM is an image from an old corporate laptop that has been reformatted since; I just need to continue running it, but as a VM.

The VPN works on all of the other corporate Windows laptops (non-VMs), with the same settings, even from inside the company's LAN. In my VM, though, the VPN connection fails with an error message mentioning Internet latency or server full capacity (which are actually not a problem at all). With some other VPN settings, the error message sometimes mentions potential GRE issues with a firewall or something.

Do I need to configure something in my VM settings, such as a NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it: in the VM settings, use **Bridged** Adapter (instead of the default NAT).